# Prevent Xcode/clang from raising logic error on intentionally flawed code

Tags: xcode, macos, clang, objective-c++, clang-static-analyzer

For testing purposes only, I'm including a function to intentionally crash my app (testing my app's handling of unintentional crashes). To do so, I'm using:

```
strcpy(0, "crash");
```

Of course, when doing analysis of my code, Xcode reports the logic error `Null pointer argument in call to string copy function`. I've tried wrapping the offending code like so:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wnonnull"
    strcpy(0, "crash");
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

But Xcode (v9.2 (9C40b)) still complains (this isn't a warning, it's a logic error, I understand). Is there some other way to keep Xcode/clang from flagging this code? Is there some better way to induce a crash that can be protected from Xcode/clang analysis error?

Comment: Is that Objective C++ - `(char *)@"0".integerValue;`? If so, you may want to re-tag the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me (no need to wrap in warning suppressions). It passes Xcode/clang's analysis and still results in the crash I want:

```
char *x = (char *)@"0".integerValue; strcpy(x, "crash");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `volatile char* x=0; strcpy(x, "crash")`

This'll work because the compiler isn't allowed to assume that x when read will be any value;  meaning any checks that it might have hard coded should be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Xcode/clang still complains using your code (2 warnings and the same error):

Warning: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'volatile int' to parameter of type 'const void *'
Warning: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'volatile int' to parameter of type 'char *'
Issue: Null pointer argument in call to string copy function

Comment: sorry - maybe int won't work, try char* ... if it works I'll update the answer.  If not, I'll delete it :)

Comment: No, I tried `char *x = 0; strcpy(x, "crash");` and while that eliminates the warnings, the logic error persists. Again, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Jon with the volatile?

Comment: alternatively, maybe `volatile int x=0; int crash = 5/x;`

Comment: No, using `volatile char *x = 0; strcpy(x, "crash");` results in:
Warning: Passing 'volatile char *' to parameter of type 'char *' discards qualifiers
Warning: Passing 'volatile char *' to parameter of type 'const void *' discards qualifiers
Issue: Null pointer argument in call to string copy function

Comment: `volatile int x=0; int crash = 5/x; ` gets a `Division by zero` logic error (not a suppressible warning).

Comment: @UKMonkey while the compiler is not allowed to optimize around volatile, it's smart enough to realize that the volatile pointer value is 0, and to trigger a warning/error (the error is triggered by the compiler front end, while code generation occurs in the backend).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the best way to defeat static analysis is to do something dynamic. Objective-C, by its very nature, has lots of options for that, since the compiler can't guarantee a 1-to-1 correspondence between a message send and a method.

The simplest thing to do is probably to trigger an indexing error:

```
[@"" characterAtIndex:0]; // or
[@[] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Even if the analyzer knew that the *default* implementations of those methods raised an exception for out-of-bounds access, it can't know that you haven't swapped them out at runtime for an implementation that handles the problem gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this only causes an exception not a hard crash as the code I posted above does and as I need to test how my app handles a crash on a subsequent launch. Thanks also for the edit.

Comment: Do you have registered exception handlers? I'm not sure what distinction you're making between "hard crash" and "only an exception", since the standard result of an exception is to just abort.

Comment: On macOS, if I use your suggested code, it aborts the rest of the method but the user doesn't necessarily see any issue, the app stays running. What I want is a full crash of the app that causes it to unexpectedly quit and for a crash report to be created. The code I posted satisfies the issue, it passes the static analyzer and causes the app to fully crash initiating a crash report I can test for on a subsequent launch. Even if I put an exception handler around the flawed `strcpy ` code, a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error will kill the app.

Comment: That's interesting... I had assumed iOS, sorry; but I also didn't think it would behave differently on a Mac.